# When I move code into a function, I get a Fatal error. How can I call code from function

Tags: php, search-engine, web-crawler

There are two pieces to this code:
One that adds documents to an index to be searched, which works fine, and a crawl() function that is a web-crawler that gets the contents of a page, which also works fine.

But, I need to add a document from inside the crawl() function.

When I move the code that adds a document inside the crawl() function, I get a Fatal Error:
**Fatal Error: call to member function addDocument() on a non-object.**

I am wondering how I can access the member function addDocument() from inside the crawl function?

Right now, I have a working version where the crawl() function returns what it has crawled in the form of a variable and then the addDocument code, outside the crawl() function, also has access to the returned variable and adds the document to the index that way.
But, that only (logically) works when I am crawling one page or a page with no links to follow. As the function only returns when it is done and since it is recursive to follow a page's links, the only content it will return is the content of the last-page.
Where I need the content of each page to be added each as a new document in the index.

Here is the working code, described above, commented as much as I could: http://pastebin.com/5ngcucDp

and here is the non-working code where I try to move the addDocument() inside the crawl() function: http://pastebin.com/mUEwQJTG

**If you have a solution that involves how to access the addDocument() function from inside the crawl() function, then please share.
Or if you have a solution that involves modifying the working code so that it returns the contents of each page it crawls instead of the last-page, please share.**

If you have any solutions, please share as I am absolutely exhausted and have tried everything I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When moving code to a function, you are completely removing its ability to access variables in the same scope. In this case, you probably (not going to go looking through your off-site code) have something like `$someObject = new myClass();`, then are trying to access `$someObject->addDocument()` on it from within the function.

You need to pass `$someObject` as a parameter to the function, or you *could* use `global $someObject` inside the function, though it's not as good an idea.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just had to pass it as a parameter of the function! Thank you a trillion times, thank you! I've always had trouble understanding scope...

Answer (score 0):

You have specified that:

```
// The below line is where the error takes place.
$elasticaType->addDocument($document);
```

Is your error line. Now, PHP is trying to access a class linked to `$elasticaType` If you have a linked class then use:

```
$elasticaType = new ClassName();
```

If not then you should create a class:

```
class Name {
   public function addDocument ($document){
         //Add document code 
         return $somevar;
    }
}

    $elasticaType = new Name();

$elasticaType->addDocument($document);
```